# how to loop json object to render data in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

> Actually I want to render the data in a table. So I want to loop the value of JSON from the result so that It will add all tr in the table.

> so I applied in one value the loop for testing not to the rest of all just for testing. But it is not working.
> So if you guys can help in the loop issue. Although it is working in index case by giving index number

```js
{
    "response": {
        "status": true,
        "is_batch": false,
        "valid": false,
        "result": {
            "qy": [
                {
                    "ti": "1",
                    "ok_e": "1",
                    "type": "14",
                    "code": "KG",
                    "ok_conversion_table_ti": "13",
                    "base_uom": "Gram",
                    "base_qty": "1000",
                    "status": "1",
                    "created_by": "0",
                    "creation_datetime": "2022-01-08 12:17:46",
                    "trans": [
                        {
                            "ti": "5",
                            "ok_e": "1",
                            "ok_uom_ti": "1",
                            "lang_code": "1",
                            "name": "Kilogram",
                            "status": "1",
                            "created_by": "0",
                            "creation_datetime": "2022-04-19 01:21:24"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ti": "5",
                    "ok_e": "1",
                    "type": "1",
                    "code": "FT",
                    "ok_conversion_table_ti": "1",
                    "base_uom": "Inch",
                    "base_qty": "12",
                    "status": "1",
                    "created_by": "0",
                    "creation_datetime": "2022-09-24 17:40:26",
                    "trans": [
                        {
                            "ti": "6",
                            "ok_e": "1",
                            "ok_uom_ti": "5",
                            "lang_code": "1",
                            "name": "Foot",
                            "status": "1",
                            "created_by": "0",
                            "creation_datetime": "2022-09-24 17:40:26"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "context": {
            "self": 1,
            "first": 1,
            "prev": "",
            "next": "",
            "last": 1,
            "size": 5,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="market_data">
        <tr>
            <th>ti</th>
            <th>ok_e</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>code</th>
            <th>ok_conversion_table_ti</th>
            <th>base_uom</th>
            <th>base_qty</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>created_by</th>
            <th>creation_datetime</th>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
            var market_value = ' ';
            for( var i = 0 ; i < result.qy.length; i++ ){
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                market_value+='<tr>';  
                    market_value+= '<td>'+value.result.qy[i].ti+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.ok_e+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.type+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.code+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.ok_conversion_table_ti+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.base_uom+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.base_qty+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.status+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.created_by+'</td>';
                    market_value+='<td>'+value.creation_datetime+'</td>'
                    market_value+='</tr>'
            });
            $('#market_data').append(market_value);}}
        );
     
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse deeper and add to the tbody

```
 $.getJSON("data.json",process)
```

Here is a map example using valid HTML

```
const process = data => {
  const html = data.response.result.qy.map(value => `<tr>
<td>${value.ti}</td>
<td>${value.ok_e}</td>
<td>${value.type}</td>
<td>${value.ok_conversion_table_ti}</td>
<td>${value.base_uom}</td>
<td>${value.base_qty}</td>
<td>${value.status}</td>
<td>${value.base_qty}</td>
<td>${value.created_by}</td>
<td>${value.creation_datetime}</td></tr>`).join("")
  $("#tb").html(html)
};
```

```js
const process = data => {
  const html = data.response.result.qy.map(value => `<tr>
<td>${value.ti}</td>
<td>${value.ok_e}</td>
<td>${value.type}</td>
<td>${value.ok_conversion_table_ti}</td>
<td>${value.base_uom}</td>
<td>${value.base_qty}</td>
<td>${value.status}</td>
<td>${value.base_qty}</td>
<td>${value.trans[0].name}</td>
<td>${value.created_by}</td>
<td>${value.creation_datetime}</td></tr>`).join("")
  $("#tb").html(html)
};

// test data
 const data = { "response": { "status": true, "is_batch": false, "valid": false, "result": { "qy": [{ "ti": "1", "ok_e": "1", "type": "14", "code": "KG", "ok_conversion_table_ti": "13", "base_uom": "Gram", "base_qty": "1000", "status": "1", "created_by": "0", "creation_datetime": "2022-01-08 12:17:46", "trans": [{ "ti": "5", "ok_e": "1", "ok_uom_ti": "1", "lang_code": "1", "name": "Kilogram", "status": "1", "created_by": "0", "creation_datetime": "2022-04-19 01:21:24" }] }, { "ti": "5", "ok_e": "1", "type": "1", "code": "FT", "ok_conversion_table_ti": "1", "base_uom": "Inch", "base_qty": "12", "status": "1", "created_by": "0", "creation_datetime": "2022-09-24 17:40:26", "trans": [{ "ti": "6", "ok_e": "1", "ok_uom_ti": "5", "lang_code": "1", "name": "Foot", "status": "1", "created_by": "0", "creation_datetime": "2022-09-24 17:40:26" }] } ] }, "context": { "self": 1, "first": 1, "prev": "", "next": "", "last": 1, "size": 5, "total": 1 } } };

// you call this in the success
process(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="market_data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ti</th>
      <th>ok_e</th>
      <th>type</th>
      <th>code</th>
      <th>ok_conversion_table_ti</th>
      <th>base_uom</th>
      <th>base_qty</th>
      <th>other units</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>created_by</th>
      <th>creation_datetime</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined this is happening bro. And it is not absorbing const in json

Comment: change to this to test then `$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){ console.log(data); process(data); });`

Comment: Note the change I did to the table!

Comment: bro one thing only, how to render other data then result.qy?

Comment: and how it can be done by loop?

Comment: You need to explain what data you want to render - for example your "trans"
`{ "ti": "5", "ok_e": "1", "ok_uom_ti": "1", "lang_code": "1", "name": "Kilogram", "status": "1", "created_by": "0", "creation_datetime": "2022-04-19 01:21:24" } ]`

Comment: I added the name from trans[0]

Comment: bro I want to render all ti values with their other value(ok_e etc) only to show in the table

Comment: What are "all ti values" remember I do not know what you want. Also Please do not call me "bro", "dude" or such

Comment: Sorry first of all calls by those names, The thing I actually want is to render all the ti values from the JSON. So it will create a proper table with all the values which include ti,ok_e, type, code, etc which is repeating.

Comment: including of trans and qy and other more ti corresponding

Comment: I still do not understand what you are missing. My code is easy to extend and it loops over all qy/ti - so please update your question with EXPECTED OUTPUT

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/mHSDWFP/Capturezz.png


this is output which only show two value but i want to have 4 ti value

Comment: Please show me a picture of how a table with 4 values from the nested object will look. The names of the nested array are not the same as in the table you show.

Comment: sir why there are four ti values then? just askin

Comment: It is not my data. Why are you asking me? Can you make a drawing?
You can see I take `<td>${value.trans[0].name}</td>` from the nested array, you can just add more of these to the table if you need.